# Can you pipe to `heroku run` without it echoing the text back?

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

Sending a small bit of output to a remote `heroku run`, I see the stdin echoed back, like so:

```
$ echo 'foobar' | heroku run wc
Running `wc` attached to terminal... up, run.2758
foobar
      1       1       7
```

I'd rather not have the process stdin echoed back, rather having it work like a local run:

```
$ echo foobar | wc
      1       1       7
```

(My real command is sending hundreds of megabytes up to the remote command.)

Is there any way to invoke `heroku run`, piping it local data, but suppressing its echo back of the data?

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`heroku run --no-tty` will prevent stdin from being echoed back so you can pipe local data to the command.